# Edit on last cell of the TAble view

Tags: ios, uitableview

In my table view cell have textView.it is custom cell.
when i select one text view it move to top position of the tableview then i can edit.

> [self.tableViewEdit setContentOffset:offset animated:YES];

this is the code i used for that.it work fine.

Last cell also move to top.but when i type in last cell it move to bottom of the last cell and move up again.
is there any way to remove last cell's bottom attraction with tableview.or how to fixed last cell top of the tableview.

when typing i used

```
[self.tableViewEdit beginUpdates];
[self.tableViewEdit endUpdates];
```

otherwise i cant keep keyboard when i typing.why i`m using above code i want to change cell height according to my typing.

Comment: Cant understand your question.Can you be bit more clear?

Comment: "last cell's bottom attraction"???? Attach some screenshot or explain it in further detail.